# Using C Functions like printf in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, printf, stdio

I've recently started write C based DLLs on Microsoft's Visual Studio 2019 (as I am used to traditional C over C++) and some reason I can't seem to get it to compiled with any common C functions like `printf()`, `fopen()` etc. I've tried everything from including `stdio` but it keeps printing `unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf` when I tried using the `cstdio` instead, it showed a bunch of errors, `identifier "using" is undefined`, I have never experienced this before as I used to write in C on Xcode. Please help me.

In case it helps my ultimate goal is to make a logger class that logs messages to a console window created by `AllocConsole`, so I'm trying to do it with `stdout` and `printf()`.

heres a pic [image]

Comment: What happens if you use the built-in project templates and build them without adding your own code first?

Comment: Proceed as follows: File-New-Project,
Choose "Windows Desktop Wizard" and chooses "C++", "Windows" and "All Project types" in the combo boxes in the upper right part. Click on the Next button. Name the project and decide for a location. Click on the Create button. Choose "Dynamic Link Library" under Application type and click on OK. Now you can include <stdio.h> and use `printf` etc. and the project compiles. However I didn't check if it actually runs as expected.

Comment: `cstdio` is the C++ namespaced version of `stdio.h`. If you write C you should include the latter.

Comment: Try to post here a truly minimal source code that exhibits behavior that you have issues with.

Comment: @Dialecticus I suppose the problem is not within the code but rather within the project definitions.

Comment: Check the project settings and make sure Ignore All Default Libraries is *not* set to Yes under Linker / Input.

Comment: i checked, Ignore All Default libraries is blank

Comment: Also I just decided to go with @Jabberwocky 's comment and create a new project as the one i was working on was written on top of a public base. And yes it seems to compile in the new project so its probably cause of some misplaced project properties